# Angular UI Router: Calling a function of a child state's controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've been working with angular ui-router and one issue keeps coming up. I hope that some of you can give me advice how to solve this problem in a clean, non-hacky way.

Consider the following scenario:

[image]

On the left I have a side nav with a list of contacts. Once I click on a contact, the details of the selected contact are shown in the `app.contacts.details` state. As soon as I have selected a contact, some controls appear in the header, eg. "edit" and "delete" (consider them just as an example, in reality these actions are more complex).

Ideally, these buttons would just call a function of the detailStateController, eg. `detailStateController.delete()` to delete the currently selected contact or  `detailStateController.edit()` to edit the selected contact (you get the idea). Of course this does not work because the edit and delete buttons are not inside the `app.contacts.details` state's view and therefore the `detailStateController` is not in their scope.

I know this could be solved by broadcasting events, but I want to avoid using events if possible.

How would you solve this?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Factories are singletons and can be used to share data and functionalities across controllers.  You can write it like this:

```
app.factory("DataService", ["$http", function($http){
    var contacts = [];

    return {
        //sharing functions
        postItem: function(url, item) {
            return $http({
                url: url,
                method: 'POST',
                data: item
            });
        },
        putItem: function(url, item) {
            return $http({
                url: url,
                method: 'PUT',
                data: item
            });
        },
        deleteItem: function(url, item) {
            return $http({
                url: url,
                data: item,
                method: 'DELETE'
            });
        },
        setContacts = function(contacts) {
            contacts = contacts;
        },
        addContacts = function(contact) {
            contacts.push(contact);
        },
        deleteContact = function(contact) {
            var idx = this.contacts.indexOf(contact);
            contacts.splice(idx, 1);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Then, in your controller:

```
app.controller("ContactDetailsCtrl", ["$scope", "DataService", function($scope, DataService){
    $scope.deleteContact = function() {
        DataService.deleteItem('path/to/delete', { contactId: 123 }).then(function(response) {
            //remove from client-side array once it's removed form db
            DataService.deleteContact(contact);
        }).catch(function(response){
            //an error occurred
        });
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've moved away from this style and simply handle everything from the controller with the list. If you delete an item from the detail controller or edit a field that's displayed in the parent controller you end up having to update the list controller anyway. When I was doing it the way you are doing it now it seemed like I had to jump through a lot of extra hoops caused by the details being in one controller and the list being in another. I generally just have a list property that's an array on my controller and a current row property that's the complete record being displayed. Then I use ng-if to check for current row and display appropriately. When a row is clicked I use $location.search to update the url and also check $location search at startup for deep linking. This results in a single controller that's a bit larger, but it's still smaller than the 2 controllers combined. If I'm only dealing with a few fields I include all of the fields in the list. If there's a lot of data, I make a service call when the current item in the list is changed to get the data for currentRow and just update currentRow.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to create the following structure in such cases.

Router states:

- `app.contacts.index` - For containing the toolbar for detail/list view
- `app.contacts.list` - For list
- `app.contacts.detail` - For detail

> Controller (for each state resp):

```
function IndexCtrl($scope)
{
   $scope.contact = {}; // For containing the selected contact
   $scope.contacts = []; // List of contacts also on the parent view

   // Define Detail View functions here
   $scope.edit = Edit;
   $scope.delete = Delete;

   // Perform operations on $scope.contact/$scope.contacts
   function Edit() {}
   function Delete() {}
}

function DetailCtrl($scope)
{
    $scope.contact = $scope.$parent.contact = $scope.$parent.contacts[id]; // This way we work with the parent contact defined in IndexCtrl
}

function ListCtrl($scope, Contacts) 
{
    $scope.contacts = $scope.parent.contacts = Contacts.list(); // Contacts Service to retrieve the contact list
}
```